# What do you call a logo panel with many signs of many companies?

Tags: single-word-requests, business-language

I can't find the word for this... Imagine you enter a coworking centre and there is a wall with little plaques where they display their customer's names and/or logos. How would you call that?

In Spanish we call it "directorio" but there is no direct translation for this.

Comment: Have you considered the obvious translation *directory* - see [Lexico particularly definition 1.1 here](https://www.lexico.com/definition/directory)

Comment: Please edit the question to explain a little more. I'm imagining a board that helps you *locate* business within an office building; beside each name it perhaps tells the floor or room number. Is this what you mean, or is it more of an advertisement or display of clients?

Answer (score 1):

I would call it a "Directory Board" or more precisely a "Company Directory Board".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Many many thanks! It was very helpful :)

Comment: Isn't that what one calls a logo panel with a single sign of a single company?

Comment: Also, building directory, shopping mall directory, apartment directory.